# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 for PurplAir

Tags: php, html, webserver, http-status-code-404

Don't flame me, but I am trying to create a PurplAir API request with PHP, and when I run the code, the result is not found.
I attached the screenshots of my code, repo, and local server.

[image: Result]

[image: Repo]

I tried watching videos, and going to other Stack problems.

---

*Update*

---

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeAPIRequest() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var request.open('GET', https: '//api.purpleair.com/v1/sensors/142696');
            var request.setRequestHeader('X-API-Key', 19E223A3-3837-11ED-B5AA-42010A800006);
            var request.send();

            $request.onload = ()=>{
                const given = JSON.parse(request.response);
                console.log(given.sensor);

                //Get PM2.5 from json
                var PM = given.sensor.stats["pm2.5_10minute"];
                console.log("PM2.5: " + PM);

                //calculate AQI
                calcAQIFromPM(PM);
                console.log("AQI: " + AQI);
            }
        }

        //Calculates AQI value (using formula from link below)
        //  - https://metone.com/how-to-calculate-aqi-and-nowcast-indices/
        //TODO: Fix this formula for ALT cf=3 (Purple Air's default)
        //  - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S135223102100251X?via%3Dihub
        function calcAQIFromPM(pm) {
            //DO NOT CHANGE TABLE
            const table = [
                [0.0, 12.0, 0, 50],
                [12.1, 35.4, 51, 100],
                [35.5, 55.4, 101, 150],
                [55.5, 150.4, 151, 200],
                [150.5, 250.4, 201, 300],
                [250.5, 500.4, 301, 500],
            ];

            //formula for calc AQI
            const computeAqi = (concI, [concLo, concHi, aqiLo, aqiHi]) =>
                Math.round(
                ((concI - concLo) / (concHi - concLo)) * (aqiHi - aqiLo) + aqiLo
                );

            //find table values where (pm > low && pm <= high)
            const values = table.find(([concLo, concHi, aqiLo, aqiHi]) => (pm >= concLo && pm <= concHi));

            //Set AQI (max 500)
            AQI = values ? computeAqi(pm, values) : 500;
        }

        //------STYLE SECTION------
        function setAQIText() {
            document.getElementById("AQI").textContent = AQI;
        }

        //TODO: fix colors to match PurpleAir
        function setAQIColor() {
            var color = document.getElementById("colorDiv")

            if( AQI < 50 ) {
                color.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            } else if( AQI >= 50 && AQI < 100 ) {
                color.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            } else if( AQI >= 100 && AQI < 150 ) {
                color.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
            } else if( AQI >= 150 && AQI < 200 ) {
                color.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            } else if( AQI >= 200 && AQI < 300 ) {
                color.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
            } else if( AQI >= 300 ) {
                color.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            }
        }
        </script>
            <h1> Current AQI </h1>
            <div id="colorDiv" height="20px" width="20px">
                <h2 id="AQI">---</h2>
            </div>
            <button id="getAQI">Get Current AQI</button>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 7 of your code (`setRequestHeader(`...) add quotation marks around your API key, it's a string.

Also,

```
var request.open('GET', https: '//api.purpleair.com/v1/sensors/142696');
```

should be

```
var request.open('GET', 'https://api.purpleair.com/v1/sensors/142696');
```

I mean go through your code again and check all the string escaping, do you know how to code in PHP? These look like some really basic PHP errors, unrelated to PurpleAir.

Once you fix these I suspect you may run into CORS issues.

When you show us your console, go to the Network tab, try to locate the request for `https://api.purpleair.com/v1/sensors/142696`, click on that then check that the headers are correctly set and go to the response tab and see what it's returning it might be interesting.